# using 404 page for ajax fallback?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, http-status-code-404

I want to make a single page website, that uses history.pushstate to change the url.
I can make my site have only one html file, the 404 page. so that no matter what url people enter, they get to that page.

My question is: Is there a drawback to abusing 404 pages in that way?

Does google care?
Are there browser quirks?

Comment: A good rule of thumb `Until and unless you dont have any other option, dont use things in a way they are not supposed to work`. Follow the convention.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to just have all URLs other than / answer with a permanent redirect to /. You should in any case never actually return the 404 status code because at least some versions of IE will display its own error page instead of whatever HTML you send back.

Comment: What version of ie? I only support 8,9,10.

Comment: Pretty sure what I wrote above applies to 6,7,8 by default. But in any case it's not a good idea to rely on your browser handling an error in some specific way. Just catch all the other URLs and return an HTTP redirect to the canonical URL you want (presumably "/").

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do that on github pages. I could put it on my server if I wanted to, but I just really like github pages. I already use git, so the easy "push to deploy" workflow is really nice.

Comment: I could just put all the logic in a .js file so it's cached, and have a bunch of identical html files for each page. But it does seem kinda gross...